# How to get product description in wishlist?

Tags: product, template, wishlist

I just started to learn Magento2 and never dealt with Magento before. I have custom theme where in wishlist I need to show product description. So here

**/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/column**

in **name.phtml** I tried to get product description but without success.

I have tried this

```
$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description')
```

but it didn't work.

Currently the code of **name.phtml** looks like

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/* @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */


$item = $block->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();



?>
<div class="col-lg-5">
  <strong class="product-item-name">
    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>" class="product-item-link">
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>           
    </a>
  </strong>
<?php //echo $helper_desc->getProductDescription($item) ?>
</div>
```

I need to get description on this line

```
<?php //echo $helper_desc->getProductDescription($item) ?>
```

Could you please help to get product description in **name.phtml**? If this matters site is on production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<?php echo $item->getAttributeText('attribute_name'); ?>
```

Works if the attribute is a dropdown